# What are the advantages of saving data to a web or database than to the cloud or online spreadsheet?

Tags: mysql, database, excel, cloud, spreadsheet

What are the advantages of saving data to a web or database (example: mySQL database) than to the cloud or online spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds a bit rudimentary, but for a business user I think it is actually a valid one.

**Let's get our definitions straight**

You mentioned `cloud or online spreadsheet`. They are not what can be considered as databases. They are, well, spreadsheet applications that are mainly used for quick data analyses involving small sets of data. Examples may include Google Spreadsheets and Online Excel.

You mentioned `web or database (example: mySQL database)`. A database is a collection of schemas, tables, queries, reports, views, and other objects. Examples include relational databases (like MySQL) and NoSQL (like MongoDB).

**COMPARISON**

I'm sure there's a lot of ways to make a comparison, so I'll just focus on what I think are major areas based my experience.

**1. Data Processing Power**

As I've mentioned, online spreadsheets are made for quick processing of small sets of data. "Small", being that I've never seen one crunch through more than a million rows of data without stalling. On the other hand, databases were made to handle even millions of rows of data.

It is worth noting that the types of reports and data processing that can be done within a spreadsheet can be matched by database functions with ease.

**2. Collaboration (i.e. multiple users)**

It is typical that with an online spreadsheet, you can only view the most updated sheet based on how it was edited by the most recent user. While there may be alternative ways to capture data changes, but you'd have to bend over backwards to make it work. Bottom line is that when you have more and more users collaborating on one spreadsheet, methods for robust tracking of data changes become very time-consuming and error-prone.

Databases (such as RDBMS like MySQL) are designed to handle multiple users with data changes. Moreover, you can easily assign roles to control what actions can be done by certain user roles and what can be viewed by them. This is certainly a handicap of an online spreadsheet, which generally only have users that can edit and those that cannot.

**3. Data Integrity**

Since user roles can be robustly defined using databases, you can add multiple layers of data approval workflows to ensure the veracity of business data.  This is simply very tedious to do using online spreadsheets.

**4. Backup**

Databases can be easily backed up as part of its automated workflows. Spreadsheets, on the other hand, need to be backed up manually (and my "manual", I mean tedious and error-prone)

**5. Infrastructure Design Complexity and Cost**

This is probably the main consideration to go with spreadsheets. With online spreadsheets, you can be up and running in a matter of minutes from creating your account.

On the other hand, databases, in order to effectively deliver the features I mentioned above, must be properly designed before it is used (or "rolled out in production").  Doing this takes more time and costs more money compared to if you were to use an online spreadsheet.

**Last Words**

So if high data volume, complex data workflows, and robust data backup aren't your main considerations, then you're probably better off using an online spreadsheet.  Otherwise, you should seriously consider developing your capability to put together a formal database management system.

Hope this helps!